# What are the actual google user webhook event names?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push), the user-related events to which one can subscribe are:

- `add`
- `delete`
- `makeAdmin`
- `undelete`
- `update`

However, in practice these are the values I've observed for the `X-Goog-Resource-State` header:

- `create` (but never `add`)
- `delete`
- `make_admin` (but never `makeAdmin`)
- `update`

Is there another source of documentation for this stuff?